# How to print out a dictionary in the original typed order?

Tags: python, dictionary

Okay so I've been searching around for this a lot now and I can't find a clear answer. Here is my code:

```
global_commands = {
"New" : "Starts a fresh game and overwrites any previously saved file.\n\n",
"Load" : "Loads a games state which has already been saved.\n\n",}
```

I want to be able to print it out like so:
Load (Always printed first)
New  (Always printed second)

How do I order the dictionary to always print it out this way?

Comment: Dictionaries are arbitrarily-ordered. Use an `OrderedDict` object, or keep track of the entered order in a sequence like a `list`.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a list of tuples. Example: global_commands = [("New", "starts... etc..."), ("Load", "loads game... etc...")]